# Creating Hibernate Criteria Query for Tables with Multiple Relations

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I've got a table structure something like this...

```
class A{
    Integer id;

    @OneToMany //
    List<B> b;

}

Class B{

    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    A a;

    @OneToMany
    List<C> c;
}

Class C{

    Integer id;

    String someField;

    @ManyToOne
    B b;

}
```

Now, I want to query all class A entries where C.someField equals to the parameter passed.

**Note: There is no direct relation of A with C.**

*Relations are like A -> List < B > and B -> List < C > and I need to check it in the whole List of C.*

How can I create criteria query for such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already changed my whole flow of implementation along with database structure, but if someone wants to implement a similar query, it can be done as below :

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class,"a");
criteria.createCriteria("a.b",b);
criteria.createCriteria("b.c",c);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.someField","queryParameter");
```

What i was doing before was instead of `criteria.createCriteria` (Criteia on top of Criteria) i was using `criteria.crateAlias` (that only creates alias) for the lists.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

The query regarding your question be like,

```
SELECT c1.name, c1.id
FROM c c1
JOIN b b1 on c1.b_id = b1.id
JOIN a a1 on b1.a_id = a1.id
WHERE a1.name = 'ABC'
```

all class A entries where C.someField equals to the parameter passed like 'ABC'

**Solution:**

```
Criteria c_criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(C.class,"c1"); 
Criteria b_criteria = c_criteria.createCriteria("b","b1");
Criteria a_criteria = b_criteria.createCriteria("c","c1");
a_criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "ABC"));

ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("someField"));
properties.add(Projections.property("id"));

c_criteria.setProjection(properties);
c_criteria.list();
```

Comment: give me your query form i'll try to make a criteria for it.